# Serializing Django FilterSet

Tags: django-filter, django-filters

I'm using django-filter (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/install.html).
How can I serialize the Filterset in order to send it back to my angular Frontend?

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def materialien_search(request):
filter = MaterialFilter(request.GET, queryset=Materialien.objects.all())
materialien_serializer = MaterialienSerializer(filter, many=True)
return JsonResponse(materialien_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
class MaterialienSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Materialien
fields = [field.name for field in Materialien._meta.get_fields()]
```

filter.py:

```
class MaterialFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
model = Materialien
fields = '__all__'
```

I'd be thankful for every help.

The Filterset should be a GET QueryDict, but all my attemps of serializing or converting it to JSON failed because Materialfilter is neither iterable nor serializable. So json.dumps and json.load and
serializers.serialize("json", filter) did not work.

TypeError: 'MaterialFilter' object is not iterable
TypeError: Object of type MaterialFilter is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

You can use send `request.query_params` back as it is already a dict. There is another alternative to django_filters which is [dj-rest-filters](https://dj-rest-filters.readthedocs.io/) which uses serialized backend and provides all the functionalities of django_filters. You can use that as well and can serialize filterset just like you do in your serializer.